# In R, how can I test interactions in a mixed model including only some levels of a factor?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

My R data frame looks something like this:

```
subject <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),each=12))
dep <- runif(12*6)
f1 <- factor(rep(c("Female","Male","Female","Male","Male","Female"), each=12))
f2 <- runif(12*6)
f3 <- factor(rep(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"),each=3, times=6))

data <- data.frame(sub=subject, dep=dep, f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3)

m <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data)
```

This is random data so nothing is significant, but let's say there is a significant `f1*f2*f3` interaction. Now to understand where this interaction is coming from I'd like to perform simpler interactions involving only some levels of `f3`. For example, how can I test the significance of the `f1*f2*f3` interaction involving only `day1` and `day2`?

Comment: This is probably better for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexhange.com), as there is a "how-to" component to it, but a larger part of the answer would be a discussion of what it even means to test a few parameters at a time. Also, note that there's nothing particular to mixed models in this question; the same question/answers would apply to a regular linear model.

Comment: FWIW, understanding where the interaction is coming from is a worthy goal, but I would approach it not through *testing* components of the model but by looking at the *magnitude* of different components ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben. I'm having difficulties interpreting the 3-way interaction and the point was to see if the interaction stems from differences between ´day1´ and ´day2´ or between ´day2´ and ´day3´, etc. I thought testing these simpler interactions would somehow help me understand what's going on. For example maybe I see that ´day1´ and ´day2´ are drastically different, but ´day1´ and ´day3´ not so much. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ben, could you perhaps exemplify what you mean by looking at the magnitude of different components? Do you mean just looking at the data graphically?

Comment: To your specific question: `data = dplyr::filter(data, f3 == "day1" | f3 == "day2"`

Comment: Thanks for your comment Mako212. So you suggest to simply select the levels I'm interested in and run the same model again, is that right? So I would do the same for other days like `data = dplyr::filter(data, f3 == "day3" | f3 == "day4")` for example, and then `m <- lmer(dep ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=data)`?